# Merging two dataset with partial match

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two dataframe df1 and df2.  Shape of df1 is (115, 16) and Df2 is (624402, 23).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Invoice': ['20561', '20562', '20563', '20564'],
                    'Currency': ['EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'USD']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Ref': ['20561', 'INV20562', 'INV20563BG', '20564'],
                    'Type': ['01', '03', '04', '02'],
                    'Amount': ['150', '175', '160', '180'],
                    'Comment': ['bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla']})

print(df1)
    Invoice Currency
0   20561   EUR
1   20562   EUR
2   20563   EUR
3   20564   USD

print(df2)
    Ref         Type    Amount  Comment
0   20561       01      150     bla
1   INV20562    03      175     bla
2   INV20563BG  04      160     bla
3   20564       02      180     bla
```

I applied the following code:

```
df4 = df1.copy()
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    tmp = df2[df2['Ref'].str.contains(row['Invoice'], na=False)]
    df4.loc[i, 'Amount'] = tmp['Amount'].values[0]

print(df4)
```

**It is showing: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0**

Answer (score 0):

The IndexError occurs when no row matches the invoice.  You can check for this and return `np.nan` (or a different default value) if a matching invoice is not found:

```
df4 = df1.copy()
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    tmp = df2[df2['Ref'].str.contains(row['Invoice'], na=False)]
    df4.loc[i, 'Amount'] = tmp['Amount'].values[0] if not tmp.empty else np.nan
```

Comment: Hi, the code is working for this dataset. For my actual dataset it is not working.  Basically, df1 has 115 rows and df2 has 600,000 rows.  Can you please see the questions here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72917212/merging-unequal-dataframes-with-partial-string-match?noredirect=1#comment128790134_72917212