# Merging unequal dataframes with partial string match

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

**I want to merge two data frames.**  df1 has 115 rows and df2 has 600,000 rows.

```
f1 = pd.DataFrame({'Invoice': ['20561', '20562', '20563', '20564'],
                    'Currency': ['EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'USD']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Ref': ['20561', 'INV20562', 'INV20563BG', '20564'],
                    'Type': ['01', '03', '04', '02'],
                    'Amount': ['150', '175', '160', '180'],
                    'Comment': ['bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla']})

print(df1)
    Invoice Currency
0   20561   EUR
1   20562   EUR
2   20563   EUR
3   20564   USD

print(df2)
    Ref         Type    Amount  Comment
0   20561       01      150     bla
1   INV20562    03      175     bla
2   INV20563BG  04      160     bla
3   20564       02      180     bla
```

**I applied following code:**

```
compList = '|'.join(df1['Invoice'].tolist())

df2['compMatch'] = df2.Ref.str.contains(compList)

# drop unmatched articles
df2 = df2[df2['compMatch']==True]



df2['content'] = df2['Ref'].str.lower().str.split()



df2['matchedName'] = df2['content'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item in df1['Invoice'].tolist()])

df1['Invoice'].tolist()])


print (df2)

     Ref       Type    Amount  Comment  compMatch   content      matchedName
0   20561       01      150     bla    True         [20561]       [20561]
1   INV20562    03      175     bla    True         [inv20562]    []
2   INV20563BG  04      160     bla    True         [inv20563bg]  []
3   20564       02      180     bla    True         [20564]       [20564]
```

here you see, a few MatchedNames are missing for Ref INV20562 and Ref INV20563BG.

****What's wrong with this code?** **Is there any other solution?****

Comment: Do your invoice ids always have 5 digits?

Comment: No. invoice is not alway 5 digits. However, in my actual data invoice is always 4 digits.  I In addition, the   df2['Ref']  has two string values. Please note that I want all columns from both dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to merge on the digits of the ref:

```
df2.merge(df1,
          left_on=df2['Ref'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False),
          right_on='Invoice', how='left')
```

Output:

```
          Ref Type Amount Comment Invoice Currency
0       20561   01    150     bla   20561      EUR
1    INV20562   03    175     bla   20562      EUR
2  INV20563BG   04    160     bla   20563      EUR
3       20564   02    180     bla   20564      USD
```